# Can I use Frobenius method when there is no regular singular point under the condition?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Problem is solve the differential equation
$$2x^2y''-xy'+(1-x)y=0,~x>0$$
and I've only learned Frobenius method to solve differential equation with this kind of form.
But $$p(x)=2x^2$$ which means when $$x>0$$ there is no regular singular point so I'm not sure if I can apply Frobenius method here. Can I use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$0$ is a regular singular point of this differential equation, and the Frobenius method will work.  I don't know what you've been taught about how to recognize a regular singular point, but with $p(x) = 2 x^2$, $q(x) = -x$ and
$r(x) = 1-x$, both
$$ \lim_{x\to 0}  x \frac{q(x)}{p(x)} = \lim_{x \to 0} x \frac{-x}{2 x^2} = - \frac{1}{2}$$
and
$$ \lim_{x \to 0} x^2 \frac{r(x)}{p(x)} = \lim_{x \to 0} x^2 \frac{1-x}{2 x^2} = \frac{1}{2}$$
are finite.

Perhaps the "$x > 0$" confused you?  This doesn't mean you should look for a singular point $> 0$, it's just that the series should be evaluated on that side of the singular point $0$ (which will mean you don't need to worry about complex numbers due to non-integer powers of $x$).